# nested tag in KSOAP

Tags: android, web-services

I have a question:

How to handle nested tag in KSOAP webservice in android ?

Comment: Handle it how? You need some more details on your problem.

Comment: Find the mentioned link:  http://pastie.org/1247567

Answer (score 1):

The getResponse call returns a SoapObjects that can contain nested SoapObjects. You just need to walk the tree and get what you need.

Comment: A SoapObject returns an object for getProperty how would you decide if the property is a leaf or a node in the tree? I have a complex resultobject that consists of some ints and strings and a list of complex objects. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: I created a separate question for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455644/how-to-parse-a-complex-object-with-ksoap

Comment: I will try to answer that with a blog post/wiki page. Give me a bit of time to get it happening..