# How to parse a complex object with ksoap?

Tags: android, ksoap2

I use ksoap to connect to a soap web service. And get a Soapobject in return. How would I parse this complex soapobject.

My problem is that a [SoapObject](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject.html) returns an object for getProperty, this can be a leaf or a node in the tree. I have a complex resultobject that consists of some ints and strings and a list of complex objects. I now somehow have to decide if the property is a leaf or another complex object that can be parsed as an SoapObject.

Is there an example on how to parse this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find this tutorial useful on handling complex objects in KSOAP with Android:

**[Complex objects tutorial with sample code](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can use this [android web service client](http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/) open source tool.
Where you needn't parse the complex response object. Its just like call a method of a service.

say, for a service say ComplexRespService with param ComplexResponse you have to just write :

```
 ComplexRespService service = new ComplexRespService ();
 CoplextRespPort port = service.getPort();
 ComplexResponse resp = port.getResponse ( "someRequest");
```

In this way, It support the complex request/response. This tool can generate "ws client stub" from just the wsdl file.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a bit about parsing a complex pojo array on the wiki now. Check it out at 
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks